# fast.ai text modeling with continuous outcomes

Tags: nlp, transfer-learning, fast-ai

I'm just getting acclimated to ULMfit and the fast.ai application, with predictions built upon a transfer learning model. Very cool stuff.

I see this can be used to make categorical classifications ("text_classifier_learner"). Is there an equivalent to "text_classifier_learner" that can be used to predict continuous outcomes instead? It seems this functionality does not currently exist within fastai.